# Implement full Diffie-Helllman key exchange encryption in java

Tags: java, encryption, diffie-hellman

I have a chat program that uses sockets for sending and receiving data. Now, I want to encrypt the data transfers via sockets with Diffie-Hellman key exchange system.
What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: You actually don't want to encrypt the data with DH. You want generate a shared key with DH, and encrypt with a symmetric cipher like AES-GCM.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, sorry for the poor choice of words.

Comment: You can not expect us to design the application for you Mehran. Please show us what you have tried or we'll have to close the question. Besides that, Diffie-Hellman key agreement (if you mean that) in itself can only protect against eaves dropping attacks. In general, you should also protect against man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Rule of thumb: You **don't** implement your own crypto. You don't even come up with minor variations of existing protocols. That stuff is **hard**.

Comment: Just to emphasize what owlstead said. This (and `TLS_DH_anon...` as well) is **not secure against active attackers**. It's only secure against passive attackers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to do that?

Use [JSSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) and configure to use Diffie Hellman.
`JSSE` is Java's socket extension for `SSL`. Using the `SecureSocket` classes which provide the same interface as regular sockets (so your current code does not need to change) but operate over `SSL` you can achieve encryption in your network connectivity.
You should study the link provided to see how to configure to do what you need.

Comment: Can you be more specific?
What should I do exactly?

Comment: There is no actual class with the name `SecureSocket`. The secure sockets classes go by names like [`SSLSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) and [`SSLServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html) and, general, begin with the letters SSL.

Comment: I finally got to what I want by setting the EnabledCipherSuites on every SSLSocket to new String[] {"TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"}

Comment: @GregS:You are right.I only meant that as classes that operate on SSL